# How to redirect example.com to example.com/abc in gcp HTTPS loadbalancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redirect, gcp-load-balancer

I have configured HTTPS loadbalancer keeping backend as unmanaged instance grp vm.In vm site is hosted on IIS
Can anyone help with achieving `example.com/abc`. when I just hit `example.com` on browser.

Comment: Edit your post and be more specific. How do you want other URLs to be redirected? The URL that you specified could result in an infinite redirection. For example: `example.com/` can be redirected to `example.com/abc/`, but what should happen to `example.com/anotherpage.html`? Which webserver is running on the backend? Depending on your requirements you might have a much easier time configuring Apache or Nginx to manage specific page redirects and at a lower cost.

Comment: Rather than redirect to `/abc` you should configure your server to show the content from that URL directly when users hit the home page.  Redirects away from the home URL are awful for user experience and SEO.

Comment: @JohnHanley when i hit example.com it should append /abc/ and other content is automatically added.we are using IIS where we have hosted dot net site

Comment: `example.com` is not a valid URL for redirection, `example.com/` is. You must understand how HTML works in order to understand how to redirect URLs (pages). Otherwise, you will be spending hours debugging why certain paths work and others result in browser errors. Please reread my previous comment and update your post.